# Why no `Set-Cookie` headers in response?

Tags: curl, httpresponse, setcookie, chunked

I found sometimes browser can't get cookies from my website, so I use `curl` to check the headers, and the information is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\jack>curl http://localhost -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: SCALAEYE_SESSION="a57cf8ebdfc379da91ad17d1d1eac706c25ae4c3-%3Citems%3E%3C%2Fitems%3E";Path=/
Set-Cookie: SCALAEYE_FLASH="%3Citems%3E%3C%2Fitems%3E";Path=/
Content-Length: 121665
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

But when I use browsers `IE6` and `Firefox` to visit, the headers are:

```
Response Headersview source
Date    Fri, 08 Apr 2011 08:48:09 GMT
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Server  Jetty(6.1.26)
```

You can see there is no `Set-Cookie` header, which makes problems. My server is `Jetty 6.1.26`. Why they are different responses? Where is wrong? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be that the cookie was already set and thus the `Set-Cookie` will not be included on the **Response** header.

See what the **Request** header looks like:

You can do this with network sniffing using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Another great tool for this is the [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin: It allows you to check, set and delete cookies.

The final point is that your server controls the `Set-Cookie` header: If the browser does not provide the `Cookie` header, the server can decide to send a `Set-Cookie`. Then your browser decides to accept the by sending back a `Cookie` header for the server to use. If you have cookies disabled on the browser, it will not send back the Cookie header to the server.

Comment: finally, I found the reason: I called `response.addCookie(...)` after `response.getOutputStream.write(...)`. I should always call it before that.

Comment: Ah, so your cookie was not in the header... it fell on the floor ;)

Comment: But.. then why did it work with curl? I'm also having the same issue by the way. Works with httpie, but not chrome 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit). I've also made sure I've deleted all existing cookies before making the request.