# How to get session value with no set-cookie in response header?

Tags: session, cookies

**`How can I get session value`** when there's no set-cookie in response header like [this site](http://www.nate.com) ?

I've already read [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592726/why-no-set-cookie-headers-in-response), but I can't  solve it.

When cookie's cache-control value is `max-age=0`, how can I maintain the session to hold status logged in?

Please, somebody help me.

Comment: It's possible that the server could be setting the cookie using client-side scripting, such as javascript's `document.cookie`.  Then, on subsequent requests from the browser, this browser includes the cookie id in the headers of http requests.  This is how some older web sites handle cookies - for example www.pacer.gov.

Comment: @mti2935 Actually, I want to make java program that can login to website automatically. I'm using HttpURLConnection to send request ,get session and send post. `conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);` like this. How can I set cookies which are in client-side or request  when I send Post?

Comment: I couldn't tell you how to do it in java.  But, in `curl`, you can do so using the `--header` option.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call